# Uploading to Azure Media Services with sas url using rest api

Tags: c#, azure, blob, storage, media

I followed this guide https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-upload-files/
and have gotten to the part where i have the sas url (upload url). From here im really in doubt of what im supposed to do. I followed the link that lead me to azure storage services - a whole other documentation specifying how to authenticate your requests and make canonicalized strings. BUT i have the upload url - an url created through many steps already. Could someone please tell me what im supposed to do when i have the upload url and want to upload a media file?
Thanks in advance, im kinda lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the SAS URL, then you need to look at the following REST API functions: [`Put Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx), [`Put Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx) and [`Put Block List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179467.aspx).

When using these REST API operations, some things to consider:

- Your request URL is essentially SAS URL.
- Since you're using SAS URL, don't worry about the authorization header as authorization information is already included in your SAS token (`sig` Query String parameter).
- You don't have to include `x-ms-version` and `x-ms-date` headers as well.
- Don't forget to include `x-ms-blob-type` header and make sure it's value is `BlockBlob`.

In general, you would use `Put Blob` operation if the file size is smaller. For larger files, you would split the file in chunks (known as `Blocks`) and upload the chunks using `Put Block` operation. Once all chunks are completed, you would call `Put Block List` operation to commit the blob.

Comment: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. This is the message i get :/

Comment: You need to share the code. Also, please check if the SAS has not expired.

Comment: It turned out i had made an error when creating the url. I added the filename in the wrong place, and that caused the error.. dough! Still i had no idea i didn´t need to create a new authorization - and was stuck, so thanks a lot!